# Overwrite styling from node module

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular and front end development in general.

I have a multi-selection select component and upon ticking the options, I'd like to see a tick in the box. Currently the box just gets 'blacked out'.

Upon looking at the application via inspect, I can toggle on and off different styling options. If I toggle the below 'off' then I get what I want:

```
.mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked, .mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-indeterminate {
    background: #2e2d2d;
}
```

This is found in: node_modules/@angular/material/_theming.scss

Is there a way I can overwrite this to essentially turn this 'off' for my component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it is possible to override styles in your component using pseudo-class selector `:host ::ng-deep`. Let me show an example:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked
   , .mat-primary .mat-pseudo-checkbox-indeterminate {
       background: lightpink; // your new color here
}
```

[You can read about styles more here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/)

Comment: Thanks @StepUp, if I put background: transparent will that essentially put no color?

Comment: @nimgwfc yeah, you are right. There will be no color in your applied style. Check it.